# WGET without the log file

Tags: linux, wget

Every time I use wget http://www.domain.com a Log file is being saved automatically on my server. is there anyway to run this command without logging?

Thanks,

Joel

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could try -o and -q

```
-o logfile
   --output-file=logfile
       Log all messages to logfile.  The messages are  
       normally reported to standard error.
-q
 --quiet
     Turn off Wget's output.
```

So you'd have:

```
wget ... -q -o /dev/null ...
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if I dont want logging at all... Not even to logfile

Comment: This isn't writing any logs anywhere. /dev/null is not a regular file, whatever you write there is not really written, so it does not take space and of course cannot be read back.

Comment: You will also want to use the -O option to prevent a copy of the downloaded file being saved (perhaps -O /dev/null)

Comment: The equivalent for Windows machines is `-q -O nul`.

Comment: `-q -O nul` may not be enough on Windows. If you have switches behind, a log file named after these switches may get created... e.g. `-q -O nul --no-cache` may create a log named --no-cache! I circumvented this by using the somewhat ridiculous combination `-O NUL -o NUL` !

Comment: If solutions does not work contact your hosting company. In my case nothing worked, and when I asked hosting company, they told me that on shared/reseller hosting cron job logging can not be disabled

Answer (score 6):

This will print the site contents to the standard output, is this what you mean when you say that you don't want logging to a file?

```
wget -O - http://www.domain.com/
```

Comment: After I run the wget command, a file named "index.php" (which I ran using WGET) is created on my server directory , with the output of the page inside it. I don't want any output, whatsoever... I run this file to do some UPDATES in the database, and need no output of any kind

Answer (score 2):

I personally found that @Paul's answer was still adding to a Log file, regardless of the Command line output of `-q`

Added `-O` to `/dev/null` ontop of the `-o` output file argument.

```
wget [url] -q -o /dev/null -O &> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it is on Windows, but on Linux, the lowercase `-o` specifies **log** output file and uppercase `-O` is output / **download file**, I use uppercase `-q -O /dev/null` to prevent output. [Wget manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options-1).